# Sheets, if cell value exist then display a different cell

Tags: if-statement, google-sheets, wildcard

What I am trying to do:

Search column "B" for the partial word "treasury", if the cell value in column "B" exist then display the cell in column "E" (same row).

Answer (score 0):

solved: `=vlookup("*treasury*",'January (1/22)'!B:E,4,false)`

Answer (score 0):

try in E2:

```
=INDEX(IF(REGEXMATCH(B2:B, "(?i)treasury"), B2:B, ))
```